# Flutter mobile app when to use cache reponse for http request api

Tags: flutter, dart, caching, mobile, dio

In recent, I am wondering the cached reponse from http request api when to use it?
What's the scenario that need to use it?
My team and i developed app that requirement always want to frequently refresh new data (I am using Dio package).
But I think that's not optimizing. I look for the cached api call so that no need to always call api. Is it suitable for the app requirement when it's always need to refresh data?

**What's the situation required to use cached api call in oder to optimize the resource.**

**All is in mobile app build in flutter

- want to know what situation suitable for use cached repsonse api call
- real time example **

Answer (score 0):

**When you might not require constant refresh**:
Certain pages in a mobile application don't need to be reloaded. For example, a profile page: Say your accessing a person's profile page via a **rest api** connected to your database, this kind of page **does not** need a reload once you launch your app. You can easily call this page from cache. The only time it might need a reload could be after a profile image **update**. Then you could notify the user to **"pull to refresh the page" or you can do something else**.

**When you might need a constant refresh:**
Say you have a list like on Youtube Home Page, obviously once the app is launched, of course the user expects a fresh list of videos or at least in a different order.